# Pygame is running slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

[image]
I am creating a game called "Survival Island" and have just created the start screen.
The pygame lags too much after doing an event (takes time to respond).

Here is my source code:

```
#packages
import pygame
import sys
from sys import exit
#initialization
pygame.init()
#display surf
width = 600
height = 400
surface  = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()#for fps
#caption
pygame.display.set_caption('Survival Island')

#variables
mousex = 0
mousey = 0
#booleans
play = True #entered playmode
canQuitOnStart = True     #game can be quitted on start
drawStartScreen = True #start screen drawed
running = True # game is running
#definitions
def quitOnStart():     #quitting the game
    #can be seen if rect is drawn [pygame.draw.rect(surface,(0,0,255),(550,350,40,40))]
    global mousex,mousey,running
    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: #quit on pressing x on start screen
            if mousex > 550 and mousey > 350 and mousex <590 and mousey <390:
                print('Exit1')
                running = False

def drawStart():      #drawing start menu
    START_Image = pygame.image.load('START_Image.png').convert()
    surface.blit(START_Image,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()

def playGame():
    #play on clicking on "play"
    global mousex,mousey,canQuitOnStart,drawStartScreen
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           if mousex > 415 and mousey >190 and mousex <70 and mousey <30: # can be seen if rect is drawn [pygame.draw.rect(surface,(0,0,255),(415,190,70,30))]
                canQuitOnStart = False
                drawStartScreen = False
                screen.fill((0,0,0))
                pygame.display.update()
if drawStartScreen == True:
        drawStart()

def main():
    if play == True:
        playGame()
    if canQuitOnStart == True:
        quitOnStart()

#main loop
while running:
    #get mouse position
    mousex,mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    # fps is 60
    clock.tick(120)
    # quit button event
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    # main function
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()

pygame.quit()#quits after event
```

After running, The pygame window displays the image.
It takes several tries to close the window after running(the 'X' on the bottom right corner)

I am a newbie programmer so.. I want some pygame courses to do (please suggest some).

Thank you !!!

Comment: I would start by trying to figure out which specific step is taking so long. Is it getting the click event right away? Is it the `screen.fill((0,0,0))` line that's taking so long? or the `pygame.display.update()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The game is running slow because you load the `START_Image` in every frame. [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) is a very expensive operation, because it has to read the images from the data store. Load `START_Image` once at startup

```py
surface  = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()#for fps
#caption
pygame.display.set_caption('Survival Island')

START_Image = pygame.image.load('START_Image.png').convert()
```

Do not call [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) more than once in the main application loop. `pygame.display.update()` removes the events from the queue, thus you'll get each event just once. Get the list of events once (`events = pygame.event.get()`) and pass the list of events to the functions:

```py
while running:
    # [...]
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        # [...]
        
    if play == True:
        playGame(events)
    if canQuitOnStart == True:
        quitOnStart(events)
```

Further more, draw the scene in the application loop, rather the event loop. It is sufficient to do 1 single `pygame.display.update()` after drawing the entire scene.

The button click condition is wrong. It has to be:

<s>`if mousex > 550 and mousey > 350 and mousex <590 and mousey <390:`</s>

```py
if  415 < mousex < 415+70 and 190 < mousey < 190+30:
```

Anyway I recommend to use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and [`collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint):

```py
if pygame.Rect(415,190,70,30).collidepoint(mousex, mousey):
```

See the example:

```py
#packages
import pygame
import sys
from sys import exit
#initialization
pygame.init()
#display surf
width = 600
height = 400
surface  = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()#for fps
#caption
pygame.display.set_caption('Survival Island')

START_Image = pygame.image.load('START_Image.png').convert()
    
#variables
mousex = 0
mousey = 0
#booleans
play = True #entered playmode
canQuitOnStart = True     #game can be quitted on start
drawStartScreen = True #start screen drawed
running = True # game is running
#definitions
def quitOnStart(events):     #quitting the game
    #can be seen if rect is drawn [pygame.draw.rect(surface,(0,0,255),(550,350,40,40))]
    global mousex,mousey,running
    for event in events:
       if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: #quit on pressing x on start screen
            if mousex > 550 and mousey > 350 and mousex <590 and mousey <390:
                print('Exit1')
                running = False

def drawStart():      #drawing start menu
    surface.blit(START_Image,(0,0))

def playGame(events):
    #play on clicking on "play"
    global mousex,mousey,canQuitOnStart,drawStartScreen
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           if pygame.Rect(415,190,70,30).collidepoint(mousex, mousey): # can be seen if rect is drawn [pygame.draw.rect(surface,(0,0,255),(415,190,70,30))]
                canQuitOnStart = False
                drawStartScreen = False
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    if drawStartScreen == True:
        drawStart()
    #pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255, 0, 0), (415,190,70,30))
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    global canQuitOnStart, play, running, mousex, mousey
    #main loop
    while running:
        #get mouse position
        mousex,mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        # fps is 60
        clock.tick(120)
        # quit button event
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        # main function
        if play == True:
            playGame(events)
        if canQuitOnStart == True:
            quitOnStart(events)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```